# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Device credential not supported with crypto

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I am trying to set up the BiometricPrompt, but I need an authentication with a CryptoObject, which seems to not be possible when the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.Builder.html#setDeviceCredentialAllowed(boolean) is set to true.

```
try {
      KeyGeneratorUtil.generateKeyPair("1", null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PrivateKey privateKey;
    try {
      privateKey = KeyGeneratorUtil.getPrivateKeyReference("test");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return;
    }

    final Signature signature;
    try {
      signature = initSignature(privateKey);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return;
    }
final BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(signature);

final BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setDescription("Description")
        .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
        .build();

...

biometricPrompt.authenticate(cryptoObject, new CancellationSignal(), executor, callback);
```

When I run this I get the following exception.

```
2019-07-03 13:50:45.140 13715-13715/kcvetano.com.biometricpromptpoc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kcvetano.com.biometricpromptpoc, PID: 13715
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Device credential not supported with crypto
        at android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt.authenticate(BiometricPrompt.java:556)
        at kcvetano.com.biometricpromptpoc.BiometryAPI29.handleBiometry(BiometryAPI29.java:65)
        at kcvetano.com.biometricpromptpoc.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7251)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7228)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:802)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27843)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```

Comment: what is cryptoObject

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject

Comment: Please add the portion where you're creating that obejct

Comment: This is currently not supported. I have no idea if it will be supported eventually. For the time being you'll have to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
biometricPrompt.authenticate(null, new CancellationSignal(), executor, callback);
```

It's more or less written (one could say *hidden*) in the error message: when `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)` is used don't use the crypto object.

It all breaks down to how your private key for the crypto operation inside the `CryptoObject` is configured.

I assume your private key used to initialize the signature object is built with `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)`. Keys build with that option are meant to be used for one crypto operation only. Additionally they have to be unlocked using biometrics, using either `BiometricPrompt.authenticate` or `FingerprintManager.authenticate` (now deprecated in favor of BiometricPrompt).

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#UserAuthentication) talks about two modes if keys are authorized to be used only if the user has been authenticated, i.e. :

- Keys built with `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` have to be unlocked using `FingerprintManager.authenticate` (now `BiometricPrompt.authenticate`)
- Keys built with `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds` have to be unlocked with the `KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent` flow

A note at the end of the [official biometric auth training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#allow-fallback) suggests to switch from the `KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent` flow to the new `BiometricPrompt` with `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)`.

But it's not as simple as setting the UserAuthenticationValidityDuration of the key to a non zero value as this will trigger an `UserNotAuthenticatedException` inside your `initSignature(privateKey)` call as soon as initialize the signature object. And there are even more caveats... See the two examples below

---

**Biometric key auth**

```
fun biometric_auth() {

    val myKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    myKeyStore.load(null)

    val keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC,
        "AndroidKeyStore"
    )

    // build MY_BIOMETRIC_KEY
    val keyAlias = "MY_BIOMETRIC_KEY"
    val keyProperties = KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY
    val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyAlias, keyProperties)
        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)


    keyGenerator.run {
        initialize(builder.build())
        generateKeyPair()
    }

    val biometricKeyEntry: KeyStore.Entry = myKeyStore.getEntry(keyAlias, null)
    if (biometricKeyEntry !is KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) {
        return
    }

    // create signature object
    val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA")
    // init signature else "IllegalStateException: Crypto primitive not initialized" is thrown
    signature.initSign(biometricKeyEntry.privateKey)
    val cryptoObject = BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(signature)

    // create biometric prompt
    // NOTE: using androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt here
    val prompt = BiometricPrompt(
        this,
        AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
        object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            // override the required methods...
            override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthenticationError $errorCode $errString")
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthenticationSucceeded" + result.cryptoObject)
                val sigBytes = signature.run {
                    update("hello world".toByteArray())
                    sign()
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "sigStr " + Base64.encodeToString(sigBytes, 0))
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthenticationFailed")
            }
        })
    val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("Unlock your device")
        .setSubtitle("Please authenticate to ...")
        // negative button option required for biometric auth
        .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
        .build()
    prompt.authenticate(promptInfo, cryptoObject)
}
```

---

**PIN/Password/Pattern auth**

```
fun password_auth() {

    val myKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    myKeyStore.load(null)

    val keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC,
        "AndroidKeyStore"
    )

    // build MY_PIN_PASSWORD_PATTERN_KEY
    val keyAlias = "MY_PIN_PASSWORD_PATTERN_KEY"
    val keyProperties = KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY
    val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyAlias, keyProperties)
        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
        // this would trigger an UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated when using the fingerprint
        // .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
        .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)


    keyGenerator.run {
        initialize(builder.build())
        generateKeyPair()
    }

    val keyEntry: KeyStore.Entry = myKeyStore.getEntry(keyAlias, null)
    if (keyEntry !is KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) {
        return
    }

    // create signature object
    val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA")
    // this would fail with UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated
    // signature.initSign(keyEntry.privateKey)

    // create biometric prompt
    // NOTE: using androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt here
    val prompt = BiometricPrompt(
        this,
        AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
        object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            // override the required methods...
            override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthenticationError $errorCode $errString")
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthenticationSucceeded " + result.cryptoObject)
                // now it's safe to init the signature using the password key
                signature.initSign(keyEntry.privateKey)
                val sigBytes = signature.run {
                    update("hello password/pin/pattern".toByteArray())
                    sign()
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "sigStr " + Base64.encodeToString(sigBytes, 0))
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                Log.w(TAG, "onAuthenticationFailed")
            }
        })
    val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("Unlock your device")
        .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
        .build()
    prompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
}
```

Comment: You can find a little demo here: https://github.com/simne7/BiometricAuthApp

Comment: This answer should not be accepted as valid, if you don't do `.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` in conjunction with `.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)` it doesn't actually do anything. All you've done is create a key that doesn't require authentication, you can verify this by not unlock the keyguard and just using the key in your PIN example.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is not very accurate regarding both - the solution and the explaination .

To use both biometric authentication and device credentials along with the crypto object follow the below steps:

1. Create  a Secret Key with `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` and `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(x)`.

```
private SecretKey createSecretKey(String keyName ){
  KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder paramsBuilder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN);
            paramsBuilder.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true);
            paramsBuilder.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(5);
            KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParams = paramsBuilder.build();
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = null;
           keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA256,
                        ANDROID_KEYSTORE);

            keyGenerator.init(keyGenParams);
            return keyGenerator.generateKey();
       }// All exceptions unhandled
```

2. Initialize a crypto object

```
Mac mac=Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKey secretKey = getOrCreateSecretKey(keyName);
mac.init(secretKey);
```

3.Use Biometric Authentication with  `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)`. Do not pass crypto object parameter in authenticate method - like this - `biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)`

Under onAuthenticationSucceeded

```
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                    @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                byte[] bytes = "secret-text".getBytes();
                byte[] macResult = mac.doFinal(bytes);
                Log.d("hashed data--",bytesToHex(macResult));
            }
```

The mac object will only work if the device was unlocked not more than x seconds ago. (`setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(x)`).

You can try using the mac object outside the onAuthSucceeded method  after x seconds of you unlocking the device to verify . Please note that even unlocking the phone will make the mac object usable for x seconds. It does not have to be unlocked inside your application.

More on this here : https://mobile-security.gitbook.io/mobile-security-testing-guide/android-testing-guide/0x05f-testing-local-authentication